# Xinerama used not on all screens

Tags: xorg, xinerama

is it possible to use Xinerama only for selected subset of screens? I have a computer with three graphical outputs on Intel HD graphics. I have one GPU so I can run one XServer with three screens (:0.0, :0.1, :0.2). However, I would like to use Xinerama on two of the screens and use the third one as a separate screen. I am looking at the Xinerama option and it can be "on" or "off". I see no option to specify which screens should be used with Xinerama.

Comment: It seems to me that xinerama cannot do what I want. xrandr might be the right solution. I need to figure out if it can be done with xrandr.